# Validating routes in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

Right now I'm working on a one page angularjs app using angular to do the routing. To log in a  user I validate their username and password using an $http request, I then redirect them to /user_home. The problem is that the user who is not logged in can go to /user_home without logging in. I could easily validate if they were logged in by checking for the csrf cookie and localstorage that I create on login but where should this validation be placed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(evt, absNewUrl, absOldUrl) {
//your validation function based on url and set $location accordingly

  });
```

to check before route is rendered

or

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(evt, absNewUrl, absOldUrl) {
//your validation function based on url and set $location accordingly

 });
```

to check after page is rendered

more info in [ANGULAR DOCS ROUTE](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24route)

Here is [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/S2HkR/1/) of how to implement it

Comment: Thanks a million, one comment I will make for future people who have the same error is that this should be in your app.run.